# One producer, multiple consumers. How to use condition variables with unbounded buffer?

Tags: c, multithreading, producer-consumer

Despite the number of similar questions on Stackoverflow, I can't come up with a solution for the following Producer-Consumer problem:

My program has three threads:

- *One writer thread* that reads from a file, saves data into a `sensor_data_t` struct, and **writes it into a dynamic pointer-based buffer using** `sbuffer_insert(buffer, &sensor_data)`. Once this thread finishes reading it sends an end-of-stream data struct represented by `data->id == 0`.
- *Two reader threads* that remove data from the buffer head (FIFO-style), and store it into a temporary data struct using `sbuffer_remove(buffer, &data)` and then print it to the cmd line for testing purposes.

I think I have to avoid at the least:

1. My reader threads to try to consume/remove from the buffer while it is empty.
2. My reader threads to consume/remove from the buffer at the same time.

On the other hand, I don't think my writer thread in `sbuffer_insert()` needs to worry if the readers are changing the `head` because it only appends to the `tail`. **Is this reasoning correct or am I missing something?**

Here's what I've done so far:

My main function:

```
sbuffer_t *buffer;

void *writer(void *fp);
void *reader(void *fp);

int main()
{
    // Initialize the buffer
    sbuffer_init(&buffer);

    // Open sensor_data file
    FILE *sensor_data_fp;
    sensor_data_fp = fopen("sensor_data", "rb");

    // Start thread for reading sensor_data file adding elements to the sbuffer
    pthread_t writer_thread;
    pthread_create(&writer_thread, NULL, &writer, sensor_data_fp);

    // Open sensor_data_out file
    FILE *sensor_data_out_fp;
    sensor_data_out_fp = fopen("sensor_data_out", "w");

    // Start thread 1 and 2 for writing sensor_data_out file
    pthread_t reader_thread1;
    pthread_t reader_thread2;
    pthread_create(&reader_thread1, NULL, &reader, sensor_data_out_fp);
    pthread_create(&reader_thread2, NULL, &reader, sensor_data_out_fp);

    // Wait for threads to finish and join them

    pthread_join(reader_thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(reader_thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(writer_thread, NULL);


    // Close sensor_data file
    fclose(sensor_data_fp);
    // Close sensor_data_out file
    fclose(sensor_data_out_fp);

    // free buffer
    sbuffer_free(&buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

My reader and writer threads:

```
typedef uint16_t sensor_id_t;
typedef double sensor_value_t;
typedef time_t sensor_ts_t;         // UTC timestamp as returned by time() - notice that the size of time_t is different on 32/64 bit machine

typedef struct {
    sensor_id_t id;
    sensor_value_t value;
    sensor_ts_t ts;
} sensor_data_t;



void *writer(void *fp)
{
    // cast fp to FILE
    FILE *sensor_data_fp = (FILE *)fp;

    // make char buffers of size sensor_id_t, sensor_value_t and sensor_ts_t
    char sensor_id_buffer[sizeof(sensor_id_t)];
    char sensor_value_buffer[sizeof(sensor_value_t)];
    char sensor_ts_buffer[sizeof(sensor_ts_t)];

    // parse sensor_data file into sensor_id_buffer, sensor_value_buffer and sensor_ts_buffer
    while(fread(sensor_id_buffer, sizeof(sensor_id_t), 1, sensor_data_fp) == 1 &&
    fread(sensor_value_buffer, sizeof(sensor_value_t), 1, sensor_data_fp) == 1 &&
    fread(sensor_ts_buffer, sizeof(sensor_ts_t), 1, sensor_data_fp)) {
        // create sensor_data_t
        sensor_data_t sensor_data;
        // copy sensor_id_buffer to sensor_data.id
        memcpy(&sensor_data.id, sensor_id_buffer, sizeof(sensor_id_t));
        // copy sensor_value_buffer to sensor_data.value
        memcpy(&sensor_data.value, sensor_value_buffer, sizeof(sensor_value_t));
        // copy sensor_ts_buffer to sensor_data.ts
        memcpy(&sensor_data.ts, sensor_ts_buffer, sizeof(sensor_ts_t));

        // print sensor_data for testing
        // printf("sensor_data.id: %d, sensor_data.value: %f, sensor_data.ts: %ld\n", sensor_data.id, sensor_data.value, sensor_data.ts);

        // insert sensor_data into buffer
        sbuffer_insert(buffer, &sensor_data);
    }
    // Add dummy data to buffer to signal end of file
    sensor_data_t sensor_data;
    sensor_data.id = 0;
    sensor_data.value = 0;
    sensor_data.ts = 0;
    sbuffer_insert(buffer, &sensor_data);

    return NULL;
}

void *reader(void *fp)
{
    // cast fp to FILE
    //FILE *sensor_data_out_fp = (FILE *)fp;

    // Init data as sensor_data_t
    sensor_data_t data;
    do{
        // read data from buffer
        if (sbuffer_remove(buffer, &data) == 0) { // SBUFFER_SUCCESS 0
            // write data to sensor_data_out file
            // fwrite(&data, sizeof(sensor_data_t), 1, sensor_data_out_fp);
            // print data for testing
            printf("data.id: %d, data.value: %f, data.ts: %ld \n", data.id, data.value, data.ts);
        }
    }
    while(data.id != 0);

    // free allocated memory
    // free(fp);

    return NULL;
}
```

Global variables and buffer initialization:

```
typedef struct sbuffer_node {
    struct sbuffer_node *next;  
    sensor_data_t data;       
} sbuffer_node_t;


struct sbuffer {
    sbuffer_node_t *head;     
    sbuffer_node_t *tail;       
};

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t empty, removing;
int count = 0; // reader count


int sbuffer_init(sbuffer_t **buffer) {
    *buffer = malloc(sizeof(sbuffer_t));
    if (*buffer == NULL) return SBUFFER_FAILURE;
    (*buffer)->head = NULL;
    (*buffer)->tail = NULL;

    // Initialize mutex and condition variables
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&empty, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&removing, NULL);

    return SBUFFER_SUCCESS;
}
```

`sbuffer_remove` (Consumer)

```
int sbuffer_remove(sbuffer_t *buffer, sensor_data_t *data) {
    sbuffer_node_t *dummy;
    if (buffer == NULL) return SBUFFER_FAILURE;

    // while the count is 0, wait
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (count > 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&removing, &mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (buffer->head == NULL){

        pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &mutex); // Wait until buffer is not empty

        if (data->id == 0){ // end-of-stream
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            return SBUFFER_NO_DATA;
        }
    }

    count++;

    *data = buffer->head->data;
    dummy = buffer->head;
    if (buffer->head == buffer->tail) // buffer has only one node
    {
        buffer->head = buffer->tail = NULL;
    } else  // buffer has many nodes empty
    {
        buffer->head = buffer->head->next;
    }
    free(dummy);

    count--;

    pthread_cond_signal(&removing); // Signal that data is removed
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return SBUFFER_SUCCESS;
}
```

`sbuffer_insert` (Producer)

```
int sbuffer_insert(sbuffer_t *buffer, sensor_data_t *data) {
    sbuffer_node_t *dummy;
    if (buffer == NULL) return SBUFFER_FAILURE;
    dummy = malloc(sizeof(sbuffer_node_t));
    if (dummy == NULL) return SBUFFER_FAILURE;
    dummy->data = *data;
    dummy->next = NULL;


    if (buffer->tail == NULL) // buffer empty (buffer->head should also be NULL
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        buffer->head = buffer->tail = dummy;
        pthread_cond_signal(&empty); // Signal that buffer is not empty
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    } else // buffer not empty
    {
        buffer->tail->next = dummy;
        buffer->tail = buffer->tail->next;
    }
    return SBUFFER_SUCCESS;
}
```

Currently, the code has very unstable behavior. Sometimes it runs and prints everything, sometimes it doesn't print anything and gets stuck in a loop, sometimes it prints everything but the last value comes after the end-of-stream code and it doesn't terminate.

I would really appreciate a solution that explains what I'm doing wrong or a comment that redirects me to a duplicate of my question.

Comment: Apart from anything else your producer is accessing `buffer->tail` without having first acquired the mutex.  You really need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting familiar with asking questions here. What are you missing in the code I provided? The thread creation in my main?

Comment: As well as `main` you should also provide the definitions of all types such as `sbuffer_t`, `sbuffer_node_t` etc.  We could probably guess as to what they are but that rather defeats the point of a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I have to avoid at the least:
>
> 1. My reader threads to try to consume/remove from the buffer while it is empty.
> 2. My reader threads to consume/remove from the buffer at the same time.

Yes, you must avoid those. And more.

> On the other hand, I don't think my writer thread in `sbuffer_insert()`
> needs to worry if the readers are changing the `head` because it only
> appends to the `tail`. **Is this reasoning correct or am I missing
> something?**

You are missing at least that

1. **when the buffer contains fewer than two nodes, there is no distinction between the head node and the tail node**.  This manifests at the code level at least in the fact that your `sbuffer_insert()` and `sbuffer_remove()` functions both access both `buffer->head` and `buffer->tail`.  From the perspective of synchronization requirements, it is this lower-level view that matters.
2. **Insertion and removal modifies the node objects themselves**, not just the overall buffer object.
3. **Synchronization is not just, nor even primarily, about avoiding threads directly interfering with each other**.  It is even more about the consistency of different threads' views of memory.  You need appropriate synchronization to ensure that one thread's writes to memory are (ever) observed by other threads, and to establish ordering relationships among operations on memory by different threads.

> Currently, the code has very unstable behavior. Sometimes it runs and
> prints everything, sometimes it doesn't print anything and gets stuck
> in a loop, sometimes it prints everything but the last value comes
> after the end-of-stream code and it doesn't terminate.

This is unsurprising, because your program contains data races, and its behavior is therefore undefined.

**Do ensure that neither the reader nor the writer accesses any member of the buffer object without holding the mutex locked**.  As the code is presently structured, that will synchronize access not only to the buffer structure itself, but also to the data in the nodes, which presently are involved in their own data races.

---

Now note that here ...

> ```
>     while (buffer->head == NULL){
>
>         pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &mutex); // Wait until buffer is not empty
>
>         if (data->id == 0){ // end-of-stream
>             pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
>             return SBUFFER_NO_DATA;
>         }
>     }
> ```

... you are testing for an end-of-data marker before actually reading an item from the buffer.  It looks like that's useless in practice.  In prarticular, it does not prevent the end-of-stream item from being removed from the buffer, so only one reader will see it.  The other(s) will then end up waiting indefinitely for data that will never arrive.

---

Next, consider this code executed by the readers:

> ```
>     // while the count is 0, wait
>     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
>     while (count > 0) {
>         pthread_cond_wait(&removing, &mutex);
>     }
>     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
> ```

Note well that the reader unlocks the mutex while `count` is 0, so there is an opportunity for another reader to reach the `while` loop and pass through.  I'm not sure that two threads both getting past that point at the same time produces a problem in practice, but the point seems to be to avoid that, so do it right: move the `count++` from later in the function to right after the `while` loop, prior to unlocking the mutex.

Alternatively, once you've done that, it should be clear(er) that you've effectively hand-rolled a binary semaphore.  You could simplify your code by switching to an actual POSIX semaphore for this purpose.  Or if you want to continue with a mutex + CV for this, then consider using a different mutex, as the data to be protected for this purpose are disjoint from the buffer and its contents.  That would get rid of the weirdness of re-locking the mutex immediately after unlocking it.

Or on the third hand, consider whether you need to do any of that at all.  How is the (separate) mutex protection of the rest of the body of `sbuffer_remove()` not sufficient by itself?  I propose to you that it **is** sufficient.  After all, you're presently using your hand-rolled semaphore exactly as (another) mutex.

---

The bones of this code seem reasonably good, so I don't think repairs will be too hard.

First, add the needed mutex protection in `sbuffer_insert()`.  Or really, just expand the scope of the critical section that's already there:

```
int sbuffer_insert(sbuffer_t *buffer, sensor_data_t *data) {
    sbuffer_node_t *dummy;
    if (buffer == NULL) return SBUFFER_FAILURE;
    dummy = malloc(sizeof(sbuffer_node_t));
    if (dummy == NULL) return SBUFFER_FAILURE;
    dummy->data = *data;
    dummy->next = NULL;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (buffer->tail == NULL) // buffer empty (buffer->head should also be NULL
    {
        assert(buffer->head == NULL);
        buffer->head = buffer->tail = dummy;
        pthread_cond_signal(&empty); // Signal that buffer is not empty

    } else // buffer not empty
    {
        buffer->tail->next = dummy;
        buffer->tail = buffer->tail->next;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return SBUFFER_SUCCESS;
}
```

Second, simplify and fix `sbuffer_remove()`:

```
int sbuffer_remove(sbuffer_t *buffer, sensor_data_t *data) {
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        return SBUFFER_FAILURE;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    // Wait until the buffer is nonempty
    while (buffer->head == NULL) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &mutex);
    }

    // Copy the first item from the buffer
    *data = buffer->head->data;

    if (data->id == 0) {
        // end-of-stream: leave the item in the buffer for other readers to see
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(&empty); // other threads can consume this item
        return SBUFFER_NO_DATA;
    } // else remove the item

    sbuffer_node_t *dummy = buffer->head;

    buffer->head = buffer->head->next;
    if (buffer->head == NULL) {
        // buffer is now empty
        buffer->tail = NULL;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    free(dummy);

    return SBUFFER_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough solution! I accepted the answer because at first, I worked perfectly, but after some testing, I noticed that **sometimes one of the readers doesn't see the end-of-stream, and the other threads wait forever**. I noticed that writing the end-of-stream multiple times helps with the problem but I'm sure there's a better solution. What do you recommend?

Comment: @curioso, this answer already discusses and addresses that situation. The problem with your original in that respect is "*you are testing for an end-of-data marker before actually reading an item from the buffer.  It looks like that's useless in practice. In prarticular, it does not prevent the end-of-stream item from being removed from the buffer, so only one reader will see it*."  The original version presented in this answer addressed that by ensuring that the end-of-data marker does not get removed from the queue, but it turns out that that's not enough [...].

Comment: [...] Leaving the EOD marker in the queue is necessary, but reader threads already blocked at the CV need to be signaled before they will actually act on that, so I have just updated this answer by adding a call to `pthread_cond_signal()` when the reader sees the EOD marker and leaves it in the buffer.  You can consider that analogous to the reader consuming the EOD, and then putting a new one in the buffer, which may make it more intuitive why the extra signaling is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer here, but I see this in your `sbuffer_remove` function:

```c
    // while the count is 0, wait
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (count > 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&removing, &mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

That looks suspicious to me. What is the purpose of waiting for the `count` to become zero? Your code waits for the count to become zero, but then it does nothing else before it unlocks the mutex.

I don't know what `count` represents, but if the other reader thread is concurrently manipulating it, then there is no guarantee that it will *still* be zero once you've unlocked the mutex.

But, maybe that hasn't caused a problem for you because...

---

...This also looks suspicious:

```c
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
```

Why do you unlock the `mutex` and *immediately* lock it again? Are you thinking that will afford the other consumer a chance to lock it? *Technically* speaking, it does that, but in practical terms, the chance it offers is known as, "a snowball's chance in Hell." If thread A is waiting for a mutex that is locked by thread B, and thread B unlocks and then immediately tries to re-lock, then in most languages/libraries/operating systems, thread B will almost always succeed while thread A goes back to try again.

Mutexes work best when they are rarely contested. If you have a program in which threads spend any significant amount of time waiting for mutexes, then you probably are not getting much benefit from using multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. `count` refers to the reader thread count. I thought that using the condition variable like that would guarantee that **only one of the reader threads at a time is reaching the critical section where the buffer is modified**.  What do you suggest to achieve this?

Comment: Regarding your second remark. I was indeed trying to make the consumers compete for it, but now I see why this is a problem. How can I make the two threads "compete" in a fair way and avoid both of them altering the buffer at the same time?

Comment: Some languges/libraries/operating systems offer something called a "fair" mutex, where the lock always is awarded to the thread that's been waiting longest. Pthreads doesn't have that feature, and most programmers never want it anyway because if you need it, you're probably trying to prop up a bad design.

Comment: Threads are expensive. Objects are cheap. Don't use threads as a substitute for objects.\* There's nothing wrong with having worker threads compete for tasks. But if your two consumer threads can not _concurrently_ work on their tasks, then why make them separate threads? You could have just one consumer thread that works on behalf of two or more different consumer _objects._ One design principle that I follow is: If there's something that needs to be done, it should not matter which thread does it. Its better for a thread to just do something instead of waiting for some other thread to do it.

Comment: \*There is a certain other programming language whose community is working to make threads as cheap as objects. It won't help you of course, but just in case you are interested... https://www.baeldung.com/openjdk-project-loom